# new Map is not adding value in lwc

Tags: javascript, map, lwc-wire-adapter

I want to put my result( which returned from apex class) in Map to use in other place. But my map is empty.

```
export default class contactUpdate extends LightningElement {


@track condata = [];
 @track map1 = new Map(); 
@track showSpinner = false;
@wire(getContacts)accList(result) {
      if (result.data) {
        let conList = [];
        result.data.forEach((conVal) => {
            **this.map1.set(conVal.Id, conVal);**
            alert(this.map1);
            let con = {};
            con.Id =  conVal.Id;
            con.Name =  conVal.Name;
            con.conRecord = '/' + conVal.Id;
            con.ContactComment  = conVal.Comment__c;            

            conList.push(con);
        });

        this.condata = conList;
        //alert('onload@@'+JSON.stringify(this.condata));
    }
    else if(error) {
        window.console.log(error);
    }
}
```

this.map1 value is coming empty.Please suggest

Comment: what is `conVal`? Do you mean `oliVal`?

Comment: updated .Yes@nick Cook

Comment: When you say `this.map1 value is coming empty`, where are you checking this?

Comment: @ Nagendra Sing after the line this.map1.set(conVal.Id, conVal);